# Как записать Json в application.properies

Tags: java, spring

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильнее данные приведенного ниже формата записать в application.properties в моем Spring Boot приложении

sampleData.json:

```
[
{
    "name": "name1",
    "description": "description1"
},
{
    "name": "name2",
    "description": "description2"
} ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Для тех, кто будет искать подобное решение** , я сам нашел ответ:

application.properies:

```
data = [\
{\
    "name": "name1",\
    "description": "description1"\

},\
...
]
```